# Get start and end index from jagged string array for particular values

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a jagged string array:

where on first row column values are like:

```
[0][0] = "A"
[0][1] = "A"
[0][2] = "A"
[0][3] = "A"
[0][4] = "A"
[0][5] = "B"
[0][5] = "B"
[0][5] = "C1"
[0][5] = "C1"
... so on.
```

Is there an easier way to get start and end index of "B"? 
can this be done using linq? I tried this:

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(0, jagged.GetLength(1))
                          .Where(index => jagged[0][index].Contains("B"))
                          .ToArray();
```

and was gonna get start and end from above array to get what i need. But this linq is not working for me.

Comment: Why do you need the Indices?
If you need start and end Indices you may really be trying to do something else.

Comment: SH- Basically its a jagged array so i need for row 0. Start and end index of C1, to change its values.

Comment: I'm slightly confused exactly what your array looks like. Its and array of strings[]? They start with the same value?

Comment: @SH- It looks exactly the same way as shown above. I am gonna edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was i doing wrong. This might help someone else:

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(0, jagged.GetLength(1))
                          .Where(index => jagged[0,index].Contains("B"))
                          .ToArray();
```

Now var a has all the values which contain "B" so it can be used to get index.